# How to use table command with unequal lengths of different columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have my data set which has a column called "SCORE"(min=400, max = 971). I want to run a PSI/Gini test hence I had split my score into bands of 50 interval, like >600, 600-649, 650-699 etc. Now after creating these intervals, I want to count the number of bads in the loans,(0= good, 1= default), hence this is another column. I want the count of number of loans per band which are good and bad. The table command is not coming of use as it says unequal length can't be used.

```
Score Score band bad loans
900    900-949    1
920    900-949    0
944    900-949    1
960    900-949    1
500    500-549    0
```

I had tried using 
table(Scorecard_PRIME$Score_band, table(Scorecard_PRIME$bad loans)) which said : 
Error , all arguments must have the same length

Comment: How about this? `table(df$Score.band, df$bad.loans)`

Comment: Its not counting the frequency wise loans which are 1 ,0 respectively

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the problem. Could you pls update your post with `dput(df)` and the desired output?